# Creating json for waypoints positions and links

Tags: c#, json, unity-game-engine

I want to create json data for saving waypoints positions and their links .

**Current Project**

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.Collections.Generic;
[System.Serializable]
public class Point
{
    
    public double x { get; set; }
    public double y { get; set; }
    public double z { get; set; }
}
[System.Serializable]
public class Link
{
    [JsonProperty("$ref")]
    public string Ref { get; set; }
    public Point Point { get; set; } = new Point();
    public List<RoadLink> RoadLinks { get; set; } = new List<RoadLink>();
    public int? LineCount { get; set; }
    public double? SpeedLimit { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("$id")]
    public string Id { get; set; }
}
[System.Serializable]
public class RoadLink
{
    public Link Link { get; set; } = new Link();
    public double SpacerLineWidth { get; set; }
  
}
[System.Serializable]
public class Content
{
    public Point Point { get; set; } = new Point();
    public List<RoadLink> RoadLinks { get; set; } = new List<RoadLink>();
    public int LineCount { get; set; }
    public double SpeedLimit { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("$id")]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("$ref")]
    public string Ref { get; set; }
}
[System.Serializable]
public class DataFile
{
    [JsonProperty("$content")]
    public List<Content> Content { get; set; } = new List<Content>();




    [JsonProperty("$type")]
    public string Type { get; set; }
}
```

2nd Script

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using UnityEditor;
using System.IO;


public class JsonKeyWords : MonoBehaviour
{


    public Transform[] wayPosition;
    List<Vector3> wayPos = new List<Vector3>();
    public string typeValue;
    //public s


    void AssignPositions()
    {
        for (int  i = 0;  i < wayPosition.Length;  i++)
        {

            wayPos.Add(new Vector3(wayPosition[i].position.x, wayPosition[i].position.y, wayPosition[i].position.z));
            //wayPos[i].x = wayPosition[i].position.x;
            //wayPos[i].y = wayPosition[i].position.y;
            //wayPos[i].z = wayPosition[i].position.z;

        }

    }

  
    void main()
    {
        DataFile mainSource = new DataFile();
        mainSource.Content.Add(new Content()
        {
            Point = new Point { x = wayPos[0].x, y = wayPos[0].y, z = wayPos[0].z },
            RoadLinks = new List<RoadLink>(),
            LineCount = 1,
            Id = "1",
            Ref = "0",
            SpeedLimit = 3.13

        });
        mainSource.Type = typeValue;

        var jsonString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(mainSource);

        var newPklayer = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonString);

        File.WriteAllText(Application.dataPath + "/test.json", jsonString);

        Debug.Log(newPklayer);
    }
    
    

    private void Awake()
    {
        AssignPositions();
        main();
        
    }   

}
```

**The Data I want**
: Json File of a project that i am learning from which do not have reference on how he made this but have scripts to desterilize and use this data

```
{
  "$content": [
    {
      "Point": {
        "x": 644.6,
        "y": 11.2,
        "z": -827.37
      },
      "RoadLinks": [
        {
          "Link": {
            "Point": {
              "x": 595.9198,
              "y": 11.06416,
              "z": -827.0071
            },
            "RoadLinks": [
              {
                "Link": {
                  "$ref": "0"
                },
                "SpacerLineWidth": 0
              },
              {
                "Link": {
                  "Point": {
                    "x": 547.2396,
                    "y": 10.92832,
                    "z": -826.6442
                  },
                  "RoadLinks": [
                    {
                      "Link": {
                        "$ref": "2"
                      },
                      "SpacerLineWidth": 0
                    },
                    {
                      "Link": {
                        "Point": {
                          "x": 498.5594,
                          "y": 10.79249,
                          "z": -826.2813
                        },
                        "RoadLinks": [
                          {
                            "Link": {
                              "$ref": "5"
                            },
                            "SpacerLineWidth": 0
                          },
                          {
                            "Link": {
                              "Point": {
                                "x": 473.6187,
                                "y": 10.79246,
                                "z": -840.8074
                              },
                              "RoadLinks": [
                                {
                                  "Link": {
                                    "Point": {
                                      "x": 446.4278,
                                      "y": 6.237495,
                                      "z": -854.9285
                                    },
                                    "RoadLinks": [
                                      {
                                        "Link": {
                                          "$ref": "11"
                                        },
                                        "SpacerLineWidth": 0
                                      },
                                      {
                                        "Link": {
                                          "Point": {
                                            "x": 419.2369,
                                            "y": 1.682533,
                                            "z": -869.0497
                                          },
                                          "RoadLinks": [
                                            {
                                              "Link": {
                                                "Point": {
                                                  "x": 410.5,
                                                  "y": 1.682472,
                                                  "z": -893
                                                },
                                                "RoadLinks": [
                                                  {
                                                    "Link": {
                                                      "$ref": "8"
                                                    },
                                                    "SpacerLineWidth": 0
                                                  },
                                                  {
                                                    "Link": {
                                                      "$ref": "16"
                                                    },
                                                    "SpacerLineWidth": 0
                                                  }
                                                ],
                                                "LineCount": 1,
                                                "SpeedLimit": 3.40282346638529e+38,
                                                "$id": "18"
                                              },
                                              "SpacerLineWidth": 0
                                            },
                                            {
                                              "Link": {
                                                "Point": {
                                                  "x": 409.2,
                                                  "y": 1.682472,
                                                  "z": -907.2071
                                                },
                                                "RoadLinks": [
                                                  {
                                                    "Link": {
                                                      "Point": {
                                                        "x": 383.9,
                                                        "y": 1.682533,
                                                        "z": -907.5
                                                      },
                                                      "RoadLinks": [
                                                        {
                                                          "Link": {
                                                            "Point": {
                                                              "x": 382.6,
                                                              "y": 1.682533,
                                                              "z": -923
                                                            },
                                                            "RoadLinks": [
                                                              {
                                                                "Link": {
                                                                  "$ref": "11"
                                                                },
                                                                "SpacerLineWidth": 0
                                                              },
                                                              {
                                                                "Link": {
                                                                  "$ref": "24"
                                                                },
                                                                "SpacerLineWidth": 0
                                                              },
                                                              {
                                                                "Link": {
                                                                  "Point": {
                                                                    "x": 379.7,
                                                                    "y": 1.682503,
                                                                    "z": -935.3
                                                                  },
                                                                  "RoadLinks": [
                                                                    {
                                                                      "Link": {
                                                                        "$ref": "26"
                                                                      },
                                                                      "SpacerLineWidth": 0
                                                                    },
                                                                    {
                                                                      "Link": {
                                                                        "Point": {
                                                                          "x": 376.9,
                                                                          "y": 1.682503,
                                                                          "z": -942.5
                                                                        },
                                                                        "RoadLinks": [
                                                                          {
                                                                            "Link": {
                                                                              "$ref": "30"
                                                                            },
                                                                            "SpacerLineWidth": 0
                                                                          },
                                                                          {
                                                                            "Link": {
                                                                              "Point": {
                                                                                "x": 371.1,
                                                                                "y": 1.682503,
                                                                                "z": -944.7
                                                                              },
                                                                              "RoadLinks": [
                                                                                {
                                                                                  "Link": {
                                                                                    "$ref": "33"
                                                                                  },
                                                                                  "SpacerLineWidth": 0
                                                                                },
                                                                                {
                                                                                  "Link": {
                                                                                    "Point": {
                                                                                      "x": 332.1663,
                                                                                      "y": 1.682513,
                                                                                      "z": -944.7
                                                                                    },
                                                                                    "RoadLinks": [
                                                                                      {
                                                                                        "Link": {
                                                                                          "$ref": "36"
                                                                                        },
                                                                                        "SpacerLineWidth": 0
                                                                                      },
                                                                                      {
                                                                                        "Link": {
                                                                                          "Point": {
                                                                                            "x": 293.2326,
                                                                                            "y": 1.682523,
                                                                                            "z": -944.7
                                                                                          },
                                                                                          "RoadLinks": [
                                                                                            {
                                                                                              "Link": {
                                                                                                "$ref": "39"
                                                                                              },
                                                                                              "SpacerLineWidth": 0
                                                                                            },
                                                                                            {
                                                                                              "Link": {
                                                                                                "Point": {
                                                                                                  "x": 254.299,
                                                                                                  "y": 1.682533,
                                                                                                  "z": -944.7
                                                                                                },
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
    {
      "$ref": "222"
    },
    {
      "$ref": "224"
    },
    {
      "$ref": "245"
    },
    {
      "$ref": "251"
    },
    {
      "$ref": "258"
    },
    {
      "$ref": "261"
    },
    {
      "$ref": "263"
    },
    {
      "$ref": "265"
    },
    {
      "$ref": "269"
    },
    {
      "$ref": "272"
    },
    {
      "$ref": "278"
    },
    {
      "$ref": "280"
    },
    {
      "$ref": "282"
    },
    {
      "$ref": "284"
    },
    {
      "$ref": "289"
    },
    {
      "$ref": "291"
    },
    {
      "$ref": "314"
    },
    {
      "$ref": "316"
    },
    {
      "$ref": "318"
    },
    {
      "$ref": "320"
    }
  ],
  "$type": "Game.Traffic.RoadPoint[]"
}
```

Now To the main Question,

1. i can't understand how he is using `$ref` because they are not in order
2. i can't understand how to create `ref` to refer like it is created in json file.
3. i am creating a list of RoadLink in which its refers to Link class and then Link refers to RoadLink again, how can i use this ? is it linklist ? any guidence will be appreciated. thank u.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand it, this is basically a graph. With `Link` being the nodes and `RoadLink` being the edges. For serialization I would assume the examples rely on a automatic reference-feature of the serialization library to avoid loops.

I would probably avoid this and use manual referencing instead, i.e. make at least one of the Link or RoadLink classes reference the other with an index instead of an actual reference. This should help make the serialization more compact, and hopefully easier to understand.

As an example you could describe a graph like

```
public class Node
{
    public List<Edge> Edges {get;}  
}
public class Edge
{
    public int TargetNodeIndex {get;}
}
public class Graph{
    public List<Node> Nodes {get;}
    public IEnumerable<Node> GetNeighbors(Node node){
        foreach(var e in node.Edges){
            yield return Nodes[e.TargetNodeIndex];
        }
    }
}
```

This kind of representation is perfectly usable as it is, but it can also be converted to a pure object representation if that is preferred, it will depend on your specific use case. Note that this representation do not allow simply removing nodes, If you do you need to re-map all the indices.